# Give access to a simple .html file to users that bought a specific ‘digital product’

Tags: pages

I want to give access to a simple .html file to users that bought a specific ‘digital product’ on my site, is this possible?

I have just uploaded a .html file to my root folder and can access it via example.com/example.html

PS. It’s a paid guide, so any other user shouldn’t be able to access/read it

Comment: When you call a static HTML file then WP will not be loaded so no advantage of taking benefit of WP API here (to verify if current user has paid..) so I might suggest to rewrite `example.html` to some param that you then check on `init` and if user has paid then render HTML content and exit, otherwise redirect somewhere where a user can purchase a plan..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: You cannot use WordPress logic in your HTML file because WP is not loaded when you call your HTML.

---

There are many ways you could protect your content. It's hard to give you a fitting suggestion without knowing your whole buying context.

Nonetheless, here's a couple of suggestions I can think of.

- Create a protected WordPress page on your site that only people with the password would have access. You can put your HTML content on that page and send the password to those who have bought your *digital product*.
- Create a specific role on your site with limited capabilities, like `access_digital_product` and use WP conditional `if( current_user_can( 'access_digital_product' ) ) { // Then show page content }`. People that buy need to register an account on your site.
- Have the content of your HTML page outputted by a PHP function, and call that function only when people have bought your *digital product*. Hooking to `template_redirect`. Something like `add_action( 'template_redirect', 'digital_product_buy_check' );` | `function digital_product_buy_check(){ if( $_GET[ 'buying_success' ] ) { // Show content }`
- And probably many more ways I'm not thinking of right now

The main point is that you cannot ***effectively*** protect your content in the HTML file with WP API because WP is not active in your HTML. But I guess it all depends what kind of protection you are looking for.  You could just send the link to those who have bought your `digital_product` keeping it secret (using noindex and maybe `htaccess` passwords). But then anyone who has the link would have access to that page. Up to you to decide :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your amazingly well written reply! I will try to work out your second suggestion, as I need something nice for my beloved users :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  Good luck on your project :)

Comment: By the way, I hope that it's not against the rules to go a little off-topic, but do you know where I can edit the 'password protected' page? I want to give it a little styling and stuff :)

Comment: There are a few ways you can go about this. If your page is an actual WP _page_ you can create a custom [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) and apply you style there, if it's a post, you could add a category to your protected page and check if your post is within that category. If it is, apply your custom style by adding a body class to that page.  You could create a custom post type and style that CPT accordingly (many overkill thought).

Comment: WP seems to add a `post-password-required` class to the entry but nothing to the body, so if you wan to style the whole page, you need to do something like I mentioned in my previous comment, if styling the entry is sufficient, you could use this CSS class to do your styling